# How to activate gravity compensation at KUKA LBR iiwa

Tags: java, robotics, kuka-krl

How to activate gravitation compensation at KUKA LBR iiwa?
There is a Class GravComp which says, that using the GravComp command will bring the given LBRs into gravitation compensation, but I can't find this command neither a method to start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gravitation compensation is officially not available yet. That means, the only possibility to get a 'pseudo' gravitation compensation is to use impedance mode with a stiffness of zero or using handGuiding().